# Insert into html when URL contains a predefined value

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to check if a parameter exists in the URL and insert a tag into

```
<div id="separator"></div>
```

It works with this code:

```
function referral(){
    return  window.location.search;
}
if (referral() == "?utm_source=fb") {
    $("#separator").text("<!--nextpage-->");
}
```

In my WP theme when I insert `<!--nextpage-->` it splits my posts into multiple pages separated by a "Next" button. My issue is even if my code works, the split function doesn't seem to work. It's like if the tag got encoded and I can see it in my post. Is there a way to insert text into WordPress post without it being encoded?

I've already tried `<code><!--nextpage--></code>` and `<code>&lt;!--nextpage--&gt;</code>` without success.

Comment: The problem is because the `<!--nextpage-->` bookmark needs to be seen by the server-side code which creates the HTML of the page. Your solution is flawed because JS is client side and operates too late in the page lifecycle. As such, you need to make this work in PHP, not JS.

Comment: Hmmm, it was too easy to be true :( I'm cursed because I don't code PHP :(

Comment: You are  not "cursed" - just learn to work with PHP!